# How to show a modal box from the server with NodeJs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have a website with a contact page. When the user fills the form and presses the button, I will catch the information in my post method and if there is nothing wrong, I want to show a modal box to the user on that contact page. This is what I did so far.

*server.js*

```
app.post("/contact", function (req, res) {
  var contactUsInfo = {
    firstName: req.body.firstname,
    lastName: req.body.lastname,
    email: req.body.email,
    regarding: req.body.regarding,
    message: req.body.message
  };

  if(sendEmail(contactUsInfo)){
    res.render("modal_success", { testing: "Hello" });
  }
});
```

*contact.html*

```
....
....

<input name = "submit_btn" type="submit" value="Submit" formaction="/contact" formmethod="POST"/>
```

*modal box*

```
<div class="modal" id="myModal">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">

            <!-- Modal Header -->
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Heading</h4>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
            </div>

            <!-- Modal body -->
            <div class="modal-body">
               <% testing %>
            </div>

            <!-- Modal footer -->
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The modal box does appear but has no style whatsoever and the background is white with no formatting. I just started web development and a very big newbie. It would be nice if you could tell me whether this is the correct approach or not.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply send response back to the frontend. Are you sending request to the backend with axios, fetch or something else ?

You can catch the response with `.then()` and inside you can trigger the opening of the modal. I assume you're using Bootstrap modal so you can use this `$('#myModal').modal('show')` or you can refer to this link [bootstrap modal methods](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/#methods)

Comment: Im sending response back to the backend using POST. I'm confused about the part where you said "send response back'". I can do that using '''res.send()''', but how do I catch it with '''then()'''?

Comment: Can you send the code here how are you sending data to backend ? I mean the front end